# LibGdx: How to set a separate viewport for UI elements?

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

I'm trying to code a simple maze with a character that moves using a Joystick (touchpad). I used a Fit viewport to maintain the aspect ration of my maze while keeping it at the center of the screen;

However, I find that that the joystick is also added beside the maze. [sample of what it looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Klw5c.jpg)

I want the joystick to be of the far bottom-left of the screen. I tried doing this using a different viewport for UI elements (including the joystick), but then the whole maze just gets distorted.

Here is part of my BaseScreen class, an extension I made to reuse in other games as well:

```
public abstract class BaseScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor {

public BaseScreen(){

    gameWorldHeight = 1024;
    gameWorldWidth = 1024;
    cam = new OrthographicCamera(gameWorldWidth, gameWorldHeight);
    port = new FitViewport(cam.viewportWidth, cam.viewportHeight, cam);
    port.apply();
    cam.update();

    mainStage = new Stage(port);
    uiStage = new Stage(port);
    uiTable = new Table();
    uiTable.setFillParent(true);
    uiStage.addActor(uiTable);

    initialize();
}

public abstract void initialize();

public void render(float dt) {
    mainStage.getCamera().update();
    uiStage.getCamera().update();

    uiStage.act(dt);
    mainStage.act(dt);

    update(dt);

    mainStage.draw();
    uiStage.draw();
}

public abstract void update(float dt);

public void resize(int width, int height) {
    mainStage.getViewport().update(width,height, true);
    uiStage.getViewport().update(width,height,false);
}
}
```

Here is also a part of my gameScreen class, where I actually code all the core mechanics of the game

```
public class gameScreen extends BaseScreen {

@Override
public void initialize() {

    //..

    uiTable.pad(10);
    uiTable.add().expandX().expandY();
    uiTable.row();
    uiTable.add(ball.touchpad).left();
    uiTable.add().expandX();
  }
}
```

and in case you were wondering, here is what ball.touchpad is

```
public class Ball extends BaseActor {

public Touchpad touchpad;
public Touchpad.TouchpadStyle touchpadStyle;
public Skin touchpadSkin;
public Drawable touchBackground;
public Drawable touchKnob;

public Ball (float x, float y, Stage s) {

    //..


    //Create a touchpad skin
    touchpadSkin = new Skin();

    //Set background image
    touchpadSkin.add("touchBackground", new Texture("touchBackground.png"));

    //Set knob image
    touchpadSkin.add("touchKnob", new Texture("touchKnob.png"));

    //Create TouchPad Style
    touchpadStyle = new Touchpad.TouchpadStyle();

    //Create Drawable's from TouchPad skin
    touchBackground = touchpadSkin.getDrawable("touchBackground");
    touchKnob = touchpadSkin.getDrawable("touchKnob");

    //Apply the Drawables to the TouchPad Style
    touchpadStyle.background = touchBackground;
    touchpadStyle.knob = touchKnob;

    //Create new TouchPad with the created style
    touchpad = new Touchpad(10, touchpadStyle);
    //setBounds(x,y,width,height)
    touchpad.setBounds(15, 15, 200, 200);

}
```

**So how can i add this touchpad on the bottom left of the screen?**

Comment: Use a separate Stage for the UI. It is the only way if you are using Stage for the gameplay view as well. In my experience, the LibGDX Scene2D stuff is great for UI but usually is difficult to use for the gameplay view and logic itself. Depends on the type of game, though.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, That's what I have, a separate uiStage. but when I apply a separate viewport to this stage, it apparently distorts that main viewport. So I don't know how to solve this issue.